# How do I compare two numbers in python(and, or, xor)?

Tags: python, binary

I am new to programming and I am trying to find the python solution to the below exercise:
[image]

I need to compare the binary form of 2 numbers for the 3 cases from the attached image(AND, OR, XOR).Bellow is my code but I dont know how to make it work for all 3 cases. Thank you!

```
a,b = int(input("Please enter the first number: ")),int(input("Please enter the second number: ")) 
m = ""
n = ""
p = ""

print(sep="\n") 


print(bin(a),bin(b),sep="\n")
print(sep="\n") 

length = max([len(bin(a)), len(bin(b))])-2 

# AND 
for i in range(length):
    if bin(a)[-1]== "1" and bin(b)[-1]== "1":
        m+= "1"
    else:
        m+= "0"        
    a = a >> 1
    b = b >> 1 
    
    
print ("0b" + m[::-1],"| AND") 

#OR
for i in range(length):
    if bin(a)[-1]== "1" or bin(b)[-1]== "1":
        n+= "1"
    else:
        n+= "0"        
    a = a >> 1
    b = b >> 1 
   
print ("0b" + n[::-1],"| OR")  
 
#XOR
for i in range(length):
    if bin(a)[-1] != bin(b)[-1] :
        p+= "1"
    else:
        p+= "0"      
    a = a >> 1
    b = b >> 1 
print ("0b" + p[::-1],"| XOR")
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators (just 'coz there are other articles out there, and the python documentation is really excellent and worth bookmarking)

Comment: @2e0byo I too thought that the bitwise operators were what was needed, but it appears they're trying to do things the hard way.  And I honestly don't see a problem with the code anymore, except maybe that the operations are done in a different order than the example.  I certainly can't identify which case is failing.

Comment: @MarkRansom fair; I'll add doing it by hand to my answer.

Comment: @2e0byo don't hand them the code on a silver platter, this is obviously a learning exercise and you'd be doing them a disservice.

Comment: @MarkRansom oh don't worry, I don't (and won't) write out the *answer* to questions like this :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first loop modifies your input variables `a` and `b` and leaves them at zero.  That means the second and third loops have nothing to work with.

The easiest way to fix this is to put each loop in a separate function, the function can't modify the values that are passed in so they'll be automatically restored.

Comment: Hello, thank you, this is what I was trying to figure out!

Comment: @sada995 I could have figured it out faster if you'd put your actual results in the question.  You never even mentioned which cases were failing!

Answer (score 1):

I've written out a long answer because I wish someone had when *I* was first learning python.  Note that I very deliberately walk through all the steps and I don't present final code for everything.  Sorry if it goes too slowly: I was trying to be clear, not patronising.  Note the 'problem' with your code is merely the use of bitshifts to modify a and b.

There are quite a few 'interesting' ways of doing things in this code which it might be worth considering the 'standard' solutions to:

### Printing blank lines

```py
print(sep="\n")
```

This does nothing at all, because `sep` is only applied when there are multiple entries.  Compare this:

```py
print("hello", "world", sep="\n")
```

Can you see what `sep` does?  The reason this line does what you *think* it does is that the default for `end` is *also* `\n`.  To print a blank line you can use `print(end="\n")`, which is equivalent to `print()`, so the latter form is preferred.

### Bitwise comparison

The easiest way to compare two numbers on the bit level is to do it with bitwise operations:

```py
a = 0b11110000
b = 0b10101010
a & b # and
```

For the other bitwise operators, see:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

### Manual bitwise

The manual bitwise problem can be thought of as 'iterate the numbers by digit and do something on the digit'.  You already have a good solution to the first problem: use `bin()` to get a string and iterate that.  But you have a few paradigms in play, including using `<<` to shift, which as @MarkRansom notes is modifying your integers.  It would be more 'standard' to adopt a single iterating paradigm.  Naively:

```py
a = bin(0b11110000)
b = bin(0b10101010)

for i in range(len(a):
   a_digit = int(a[i])
   b_digit = int(b[i])
   # comparison here
```

but more idiomatically:

```py
for a_digit, b_digit in zip(a, b):
    comparison(int(a_digit), int(b_digit))
```

Taking the 'and' case, since it's the easiest (I leave the other comparisons to you), the test is clearly `a_digit == 1 and b_digit == 1`.  So we would write:

```py
res = []
for a_digit, b_digit in zip(a,b):
    res.append(int(a_digit) == 1 and int(b_digit == 1))
# res = [True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

but remembering that `1` is truthy in python, better would be:

```
res.append(int(a_digit) and int(b_digit))
```

And if we want 1 and 0:

```
res.append(1 if int(a_digit) and int(b_digit) else 0)
```

At which point we are ready to wrap it all up into a list comprehension:

```
res = [1 if int(a_digit) and int(b_digit) else 0 for a_digit, b_digit in zip(a,b)]
```

*This paradigm is really worth learning*.  A listcomp is probably the most normal way to solve each of these problems 'manually', and the steps I've followed here can be worked through for the other cases (or, xor, nand, etc).

### Addendum: unequal lengths

As pointed out in the comments, what happens if `a` and `b` aren't equal in length?  I didn't address this, or skipping the `b` representation. (Note that `bin()` truncates e.g. `001` to `1`)  Personally if doing it manually I would make the user enter *strings* and handle those.  For unequal lengths you have two options:  pad with zeros, or use `zip_longest` on reversed inputs:

```py
a = "100100"
b = "1011100"
l = max(len(a), len(b))
for a_digit, b_digit in zip(a.rjust(l, "0"), b.rjust(l, "0")):
    ...
```

here we take right-justify to the longest length (since the LSB is on the *right* hand side).  Alternatively:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
for a_digit, b_digit in zip_longest(reversed(a), reversed(b), fillvalue="0"):
    ...
```

Note that in this case we deliberately work from LSB to MSB, so the order of digits is backwards.  `zip_longest` will fill in for us, by default with `None`, but here with `"0"`.  Note that zip truncates to the length of the shortest argument.

Of course, if your numbers are represented as big-endian strings rather than the little-endian strings you get from python's `bin()` then the reversing is not needed, and you would want `ljust` for the other solution.

Comment: Hello, Thank you, everything is clear now. Have a great day ahead!:)

Comment: @sada995 note that I missed out the casts (added now) since we're iterating a string.  I'm strill in morning brain :)  but this was skeleton code anyhow

Comment: The `zip` trick only works correctly if the two strings are the same size.  You can ensure that by using `a=a.rjust(length,'0')` and likewise for `b`.  You make a lot of good points though.

Comment: @MarkRansom good catch, I'll add that

Answer (score 0):

```
def decimalToBinary(n):
    return bin(n).replace("0b", "")

## Uncomment the below two lines of code, if you are inputting the numbers in decimal format
# bin_a = str(decimalToBinary(int(input("Enter first number: "))))
# bin_b = str(decimalToBinary(int(input("Enter second number: "))))

## Uncomment the below two lines of code, if you are inputting the numbers in binary format
# bin_a = str(int(input("Enter first number: ")))
# bin_b = str(int(input("Enter second number: ")))

len_bin_a = len(bin_a)
len_bin_b = len(bin_b)

if len_bin_a > len_bin_b:
    bin_b = "0" * (len_bin_a - len_bin_b) + bin_b

elif len_bin_a < len_bin_b:
    bin_a = "0" * (len_bin_b - len_bin_a) + bin_a

or_result = "".join([str(int(bin_a[i]) | int(bin_b[i])) for i in range(len(bin_a))])
and_result = "".join([str(int(bin_a[i]) & int(bin_b[i])) for i in range(len(bin_a))])
xor_result = "".join([str(int(bin_a[i]) ^ int(bin_b[i])) for i in range(len(bin_a))])

print(or_result + "\tOR")
print(and_result + "\tAND")
print(xor_result + "\tXOR")
```

I will leave a link below if you wanna wander deep into Bitwise Operators in Python

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bitwise-operators/

Hope the code serves the purpose

Regards